# Nightmare trying to install Ubuntu 15 alongside Windows 8

Tags: boot

This process is terrible for many newbies like me, and I have tried everything imaginable to get this to work. Is there someone who can walk me through it step by step somewhere/somehow?

Comment: you need to fix the uefi boot stuff first then install. turn off the option from bios before installing ubuntu. it will work.

Comment: Check [installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi). It has got everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Well 
First you will have to make a bootable usb/cd .

You can easily do it with the help of a programme named rufus for windows it is very small.

Then you will have to plug in the usb/cd containing ubuntu to your device and after that restart your computer and on the screen , below the logo of the company of your computer you will see two options , one will be named 'change boot device order' or something like that , open it and change the order of booting by placing the device containing ubunu at the top .

Now when your pc turns on it will startup with ubuntu and you can easily install it .

Try to install it and at the step where you encounter any problem , comment and I(or someone else) will surely help you.

Answer (score 0):

[www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3)

open  it, and show it where your **Ubuntu ISO Image** is and **USB**. Wait for completion. then `reboot` your PC and in a screen you will see **f12** for boot menu and **f2** for setup but it may very according your motherboard **press boot option f12 choose usb** and it may load os **into ram or** show menu in both you have the option to **Install Ubuntu** press and wait then follow the instructions.  Note, choose **Alongside with Windows 8**.